# Docker Container port access

Tags: docker, containers

I have created an image from an existing dotnet application I can run locally.

in my docker file I have
`EXPOSE 5000`

In the docker compose:
`ports: [5000:5000]`

I start the container using the command:
`docker run -d -p 5000:5000 --name my-reports my-reports:latest`

running the `docker ps`  command :

```
     NAMES
106c4929c0d6   my-reports:latest   "dotnet my-reports"   8 minutes ago   Up 8 minutes   0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp   my-reports
```

The output of the entrypoint:

```
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[14]
      Now listening on: http://localhost:5000
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: C:\app
```

netstat shows:

```
C:\app>netstat -a

Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:5985           106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49152          106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49153          106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49154          106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49155          106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:49160          106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
  TCP    127.0.0.1:5000         106c4929c0d6:0         LISTENING
```

But I get timeouts trying to access the port from my machine via localhost:5000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is that your app listens on `localhost`. This is only available inside the container.

You need to make your app listen on the public network interface. Most easy achieved by using `0.0.0.0` as IP, which makes it listen on all interfaces.

In your case, make the app listen on `0.0.0.0:5000`.

Comment: do I do this in the "iisSettings" section in the launchsettings.json?

Comment: @RobinHalabicki, I am not familiar with dotnet I cannot tell you how you have to configure your code to bind a particular network interface.   If you show me some documentation about the particular way you have created the app, I may be able to tell you.

Comment: in the docker```
RUN SET ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have already provided flag --name my-reports but your container is reporting the name as "vpi-harmony-reports". Do kill the container and re-run the docker command. Also make sure you do not have firewall blocking 5000 port.

Comment: that was a privacy edit that was missed.   I don't believe I have a firewall issue as turning off the firewall doesn't help